# Show that $f(x, y) = (x+y, x-y)$ is a bijection.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Show that the function $f: \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x, y) = (x+y, x-y)$ is a bijection.

I tries this by matrix inverse method but i am not able to solve the problem.

Please someone guide me to the solution.

Comment: There are many ways to do that, probably one of the easiest is to show that $f(x,y)=(0,0)$ has the unique solution $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

Comment: Let $a=x+y$ and $b=x-y$. If you add them, you can solve for $x$ in terms of $a$ and $b$. Similarly, try to find $b$ in terms of $x$ and $y$. What does this tell you about the existence of an inverse function? What can you now deduce about bijectivity of $f$?

Comment: @leoli1 yes, that's an elegant way. The kernel of the transform is {0} iff it is 1-1.

Comment: You can check this - similar problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1104870/prove-that-fx-y-2xy-x4y-is-bijective

Comment: Interesting aside.  $f(x, y) = (x+y, x-y)$ on $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ is not bijective.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Injectivity:** $f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)\implies(x_1+y_1,x_1-y_1)=(x_2+y_2,x_2-y_2)$. So $(x_1+y_1)+(x_1-y_1)=(x_2+y_2)+(x_2-y_2)$ and $(x_1+y_1)-(x_1-y_1)=(x_2+y_2)-(x_2-y_2)$.
2. **Surjectivity:** For $(k,m)\in\Bbb R^2,f\left(\frac{k+m}2,\frac{k-m}2\right)=(k,m)$.

---

Alternatively note that $f$ is a linear transformation with the matrix \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix} which is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution using linear algebra:** I suggest the notation $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$, but as Arthur pointed out, there is no need to change the notation.  Now returning to the problem in your question, note that the $f$ is a linear map and the $\color{blue}{\text{matrix representation}}$  is $$[f]=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$ and we can see that $$\det([f])=\det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}=(-1\cdot 1)-(1\cdot 1)=-1-1=-2\not=0.$$
So, $[f]$ is an $\color{blue}{\text{invertible matrix}}$ and therefore $f$ is a $\color{blue}{\text{bijective function}}$.

Comment: I see no reason to require $\Bbb R^2$ over $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$. They mean the exact same thing (at least for linear algebra purposes).

Comment: Dear @Arthur of course $\Bbb R^{n}\times \Bbb R^{m}$ is the same that $\Bbb R^{n+m}$, but in linear algebra the notation of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is more common than (at least for me) $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$. However, thank you very much for your observation.